# How to order H2 tags into a list Jsoup

Tags: java, android, parsing, web, jsoup

I want to pull a h2 class that contains multiple variations of it. The posttitle h2 class contains every post title.

```
<h2 class="posttitle">
<a href="website.com"rel="bookmark">    Text</a>
</h2>
```

I want to pull each individual into my application using jsoup. I have already been able to pull all the texts from the "postitle" class.

```
@Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        try {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://uhsswordandshield.com").get();
            Feed = doc.select("h2.posttitle a[href]").text();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

The context is that it is my School's new website and I would like to pull the title of news articles. The title of each articles are part of the posttitle class.

This is what it looks like right now:
Title 1 Title 2 Title 3 Title 4....

What I want:
Title 1
Title 2
Title 3
Title 4
...

I am able to put it into a textview, but it all shows up as a big clump where all the titles are just put together. I would like to put each individual posttitle into an array list. Could someone please tell me if this is possible and how I would go about doing this. Thanks!

**EDIT**
I changed the code a little bit and I no longer get any errors.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   public static ArrayList<String> titles;
//Declare Listview
public ListView lv ;
//Array Adapter
public ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, titles);
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
    lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
//call AsyncTask
        new Feed().execute();


}
//Async Test
private class Feed extends AsyncTask<String,Void,ArrayList<String>>{

    //Get post title class
    @Override
    protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(String... voids) {

        try {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://uhsswordandshield.com").get();
            Elements e = doc.select("h2.posttitle");
            for (Element el:e) {
            titles.add(el.text());
            }}
         catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return titles;
    }
}
}
```

However, this causes me to get a null pointer exception error and my app crashes everytime.

**EDIT**
So I was able to figure out why I got null pointer exception. I was calling my array list before I declared it. However, I still have not been able to get the posttitle to be added to the array list. This is my main activity right now.

```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   public ArrayList<String> titles = new ArrayList<String>();

   //Declare Listview

//Array Adapter
public ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);

    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, titles);
    lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    //Declare Button
    new Feed().execute();




        }



//call AsyncTask




//Async Test
private class Feed extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,ArrayList<String>>{

    //Get post title class
    @Override
    protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(Void... voids) {


        try {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://uhsswordandshield.com").get();
            Elements e = doc.select("h2.posttitle");
            for (Element el:e) {
            titles.add(el.text());
            }}
         catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return titles;
    }
}
}
```